# Version for 'redis-server' was not found

Tags: docker, ubuntu, redis, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install redis for a specific version on an image.

I followed the [blog](https://devhacksandgoodies.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/ubuntudebian-how-to-install-specific-version-of-redis-server/), which points me to the [ppa:chris-lea](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/redis-server). However, I gets

```
E: Version '4:4.0.6-1chl1~zesty1' for 'redis-server' was not found
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    software-properties-common curl \
 && add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/redis-server \
 && apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y redis-server=4:4.0.6-1chl1~zesty1 \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Longer error message regarding installing redis.

```
 Redis is an open source, advanced key-value store. It is often referred to as a data structure server since keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets and sorted sets.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/redis-server
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpu6tt52qk/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpu6tt52qk/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key C7917B12 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpu6tt52qk/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key C7917B12: public key "Launchpad chrislea" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu xenial InRelease [17.5 kB]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1137 B]
Fetched 18.7 kB in 0s (30.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Version '4:4.0.6-1chl1~zesty1' for 'redis-server' was not found
```

I did run another `apt-get update` before installing redis. Where did I do wrong? Please let me know if I do not provide enough information.

One related question is https://askubuntu.com/questions/586082/apt-get-cannot-install-specific-version-listed-in-apt-cache-policy

My Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825

Comment: Are you sure that Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) should find the package, which has been published for Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty)? May I ask why you cannot use the official `redis` image?

Comment: I am not sure that I can find it. Thanks for bringing that up. The team previously use `Alpine` with redis `4.0.6`. We decide to migrate to Ubuntu. The reason to keep the version is I afraid updating would break other part of the code base. @gesellix